# How to make content take up 100% of height and width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm so close but I can't get this to work like I want it. I'm trying to get the header and the menu to always be visible and have the content take up the rest of the view screen and have it's own scrollbar when it overflows. The problem is that the width of the content isn't being stretched to the right and I get a scroll bar in the middle of my page. I also can't get it to take up the rest of the remaining window height, if I set the height to 100% it wants to use the whole window height instead of what is left.

I'm only working with IE7 or better so need to worry about javascript and am not averse to using jQuery if it can solve this problem!

http://pastebin.com/x31mGtXr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it ended up for anyone that is curious. I had to cheat using some jQuery, but it did the trick and now it looks great when I resize it as well. :)

```
<style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            font-family: 'Calibri','Tahoma','Arial', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #top{
            width: 100%;
        }
        #container{
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #menu {
            float: left;
            width: 12em;
        }
        #content {                
            overflow: auto;
            border-left: black solid 1px;
            padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
        }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function rez(){
            $('#content').css('height', $(window).height()-$('#top').height());
            $('#content').css('min-height', $('#menu').height());                
            $('#container').css('height', $(window).height()-$('#top').height());
        };
        $(window).resize(function() {
          rez();
        });
        $(window).load(function () {
          rez();
        });
</script>


<body>
    <div id="top">
        <tiles:insert page='/WEB-INF/jsp/template/header.jsp'/>
        <div id="top-space" style="border-bottom: gray solid 1em;"></div>
    </div>        
    <div id="container">            
        <div id="menu">
            <tiles:insert page='/WEB-INF/jsp/template/menu.jsp'/>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <tiles:get name='content'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Like [this](http://pastebin.com/aQGRGXS6)?

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Calibri','Tahoma','Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height:90%;
    float: left;
    margin-left:12em;
    border-left: black solid 1px;
    padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
}
```

Comment: Close but I still get a scrollbar in the middle of the browser when the content overflows.

Comment: If you get horizontal scrollbar you could try to put some `width` on `#content`. I am terribly sorry but i dont have IE7 handy at the moment to test this, but also note that this does not work in Chrome (with `width` on `#content` set in %, but it works if you set it in px or em.)

Comment: I'm getting the vertical scrollbar in the middle of the window. I can set the #content width, but how do I know how much space is necessary to fill up the rest of the window?

Comment: You can try putting it 50% or something, just to se if the scrollbar goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the float declaration on the "content" div and it will stretch to fit the parent width, remove the margin on that same div because it's unnecessary and is causing the Chrome issue.

Re: the height issue... is the "top" div a defined height?  If so, you could have a setup like the (albeit kinda dirty) following:

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#top {
    height: 100px; // assumes top has a defined height
    left: 0;
    position: absolute; // lay it on top of the page
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px; // push content down by value of top
    width: 12em;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#topSpacer {
    height: 100px; // push content down by value of top
}
```

Then just add the spacer to the content well:

```
<div id="content"><div id="topSpacer"></div></div>
```

If you are strict about your semantics, or the "top" div is of varying width, then you could generate a JavaScript solution where you set the height of "content" to the height of "top" + (the viewport height - "top") on load and when the browser is resized.  Pretty trivial to do with a framework like jQuery, not so much without one.

Comment: This should work i think. It doesn't make difference in FF and it still wont work in Chrome but it should sufice for IE.

Comment: Yes, the scrollbar on the right goes under the browser, it's kinda of hard to describe. Here is a pic.

http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/4526/22037006.png

Comment: As Billy said, remove the margin too, that will fix issues in Chrome.  Also, see the updated post about the issue in the screenshot.

Comment: Just so we are all clear, this is the current version of the document that I have and it's exhibiting the behavior en screen shot in Chrome, Firefox and IE7. pastebin.com/FiUC0zcC

Answer (score 0):

take off your left margin. When a floated element contains padding on the same side as it is floated, IE will double the margin. Add it to padding or better yet, to the padding of the element it contains.. like P.

Comment: I did remove the margin, and replaced it with a 1em padding. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Just so we are all clear, this is the current version of the document that I have and it's exhibiting the behavior en screen shot in Chrome, Firefox and IE7.
http://pastebin.com/FiUC0zcC